# Filter pipe with Ngrx does not work correctly

Tags: angular

When the page first starts there are no errors, after I type a single letter in the search input I get a :

> . ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed
>   after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined: '. Current value:
>   'undefined: c'.

Also the filter works until I type three letter then it stops filtering and its not until I go to another page and comeback that it reacts.

The filtering string is in another component, which sets the filtering string through a reducer and it subscribe where the actual list is called, in which it's proven to get the string successfully.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried setting the conditional in the pipe to not allow to go through if any of the value provided are null and also within the subscription.

HTML

```
<tr *ngFor="let shoe of products | filter:filteringString:'model'; let i = index;">
  <th>{{ i + 1 }}</th>
  <td>{{ shoe.model }}</td>
  <td>{{ shoe.size }}</td>
  <td>{{ shoe.color }}</td>
  <td>{{ shoe.status }}</td>
  <td>{{ shoe.quantity }}</td>
  <td>{{ shoe.creationDate }}</td>
</tr>
```

ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.obtainShoes();
}
ngOnDestroy(): void {
  this.storeSub.unsubscribe();
}

obtainShoes = () => {
  this.storeSub = this.store.select('StockReducer').subscribe( 
  stockState => {
      this.products = stockState.stock;
      this.filteringString = stockState.filterString;
      console.log('filtering string is, ', this.filteringString);
  });
}
```

PIPE

```
transform(value: any, filterString: string, propName: string): any {
    if (value.length === 0 || !filterString || !propName) {
      return value;
    }

    return value.filter((product) => {
      const re = new RegExp(filterString, 'gi');
      return re.test(product[propName]);
    });
}
```

I expect for it to just filter the array and show me the results accordingly and show me the whole list back when the filtering string is '' again.

Comment: Do you use the `OnPush` strategy ?

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz for the same?